# Azure Powershell - Add User to Group, filtered by license

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

Been trying to create a Powershell script to achieve the following.

1. Check which users have a specific license assigned
2. assign these users to a specific security group.

`Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "DEVELOPERPACK_E5"} | Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectID c1ec272d-e0d2-496c-ba65-602e7d822c75`

The first part of the script runs okay `Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "DEVELOPERPACK_E5"}` which returns the users that have the license, however when trying to pipe results to "AddAzureADGroupMember" an error occurs.`

Error:

````
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "DEVEL ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Onlin...omation.GetUser:GetUser) [Get-MsolUser], PipelineStoppedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException: The pipeline has been stopped.
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Pipe.AddToPipe(Object obj)
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.Pipe.AddItems(Object objects)
   at System.Security.SecurityContext.Run(SecurityContext securityContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.WriteObject(Object sendToPipeline, Boolean enumerateCollection)
   at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.WriteObject(Object sendToPipeline, Boolean enumerateCollection)
       at Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MsolCmdlet.ProcessList(SearchDefinition searchDefinition, Int32 maxResultsSize) in X:\bt\1067178\repo\src\dev\PowerShell.V1\modules\psmodule\Cmdlets\MsolCmdlet.cs:line 372,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.G
   etUser

Add-AzureADGroupMember : Error occurred while executing AddGroupMember
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Invalid object identifier 'Microsoft.Online.Administration.User'.
RequestId: be0ee2c5-44e0-41f3-a9e2-f8396980cf6b
DateTimeStamp: Fri, 22 Oct 2021 10:37:21 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:86
+ ... PACK_E5"} | Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId c1ec272d-e0d2-496c-ba65- ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-AzureADGroupMember], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.AddGroupMember```
````

Comment: Could you please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-ps-examples#get-all-users-with-license-errors-in-a-group ,It may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this done with below, appreciate all help with this.

```
$Users = (Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "DEVELOPERPACK_E5"}) | select -expand ObjectId

foreach ($User in $Users) {
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId 'c1eXXX2d-XXX2-496c-ba65-6XXXXXXXX5' -RefObjectId ($user)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is you are not using the `refobjectiD` .
You can try to use the below `cmdlt` with `foreach` to achieve your requirement

```
Get-AzureADUser | Where-Object {($_.AssignedLicenses).SkuId -match "*******"} | ForEach-Object { Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectID ****** -RefObjectId $_.ObjectId}
```

Here is my output screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I've ran the command but it doesn't seem to be adding the users to the groups. Would I need to change the " -ObjectID ****** " part of the command to a variable so it can iterate through each user?

Comment: The `-ObjectID ******` is the ID of the group ,and the `RefObjectId` is the user object id that we have collected from get-user command.